# NSLibararyDirectory visible to user

Tags: ios, security

I am storing some files and also my core data sqlite store in the `Library Directory`. As far as i know it should be invisible to user but i can still see its content with tools like iFunBox and iExplorer. Is there a way to prevent this?

This is how i am storing my core data store and all the other files:

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's invisible to the user?

Comment: @Abizern Thats what i read in resources around the web. What can i do instead?

Comment: Look up NSFileProtectionComplete.

Comment: @Abizern you are a life saver my friend! by the way does NSFileProtectionComplete work with development versions?

Comment: You mean for things like TestFlight? Should do, yes.

Comment: @Abizern no i mean just running the app on a device with a development provisioning profile. by the way make your comment an answer so i can mark it as the correct answer. and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can set files to be encrypted by setting the `NSFileProtection` key for the attributes of a file to `NSFileProtectionComplete`

Comment: I checked and it seems like NSFileProtectionComplete only protects the files when the device is locked. It does not hide the files from viewing in tools like ifunbox and iexplorer!

Comment: No it doesn't. If you have a file on your device, it doesn't hide it, just as having a file on your desktop means it can be seen by anyone. All you can really do is protect it or encrypt it. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-706/